# Uber Eats ride request API

Tags: uber-api

i am creating a food delivery platform like just eats for restaurants. Can i integrate the Uber eats API into my platform for Uber to fulfill the courier part of the delivery from the restaurant to the customer?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the POS integration via. uber eats API. You can follow the steps here https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/introduction#pos-integration

Also https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/introduction#implementation-overview

Comment: I had no idea Uber Eats had a hidden API. Thanks for sharing these links.